# Execute 2 functions one after the other in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have two functions which provide data to my page in AngularJS.
Because they provide data, I execute them like below `ng-init = "function1(); function2();"`

This all works great no problem. But because these functions don't finish at the same time, I have some part of my site loaded and another not loaded.

I would like to execute them sequentially, once function 1 returns success or error the  execute function 2. Both functions simple fetch data using `$http` and return a JSON which I add to an empty `$scope`.

Functions below;

```
$scope.getRestOpen = function () {
    $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: "http://www.example.co.uk/php/x/open-get.php",
        data: $.param({ 'location' : $scope.l, 
                       'time' : $scope.t,
                       'day' : $scope.d,
                       'type' : 'get_restopen' }),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).
    success (function(data, status, headers, config){
        if(data.success && !angular.isUndefined(data.data) ){
            $scope.open = data.data;
        } else {
            $scope.open = [];
        }
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        //$scope.messageFailure(data.message);
    });
}

$scope.getRestClosed = function () {
    $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: "http://www.ecample.co.uk/php/x/closed-get.php",
        data: $.param({ 'location' : $scope.l, 
                       'time' : $scope.t,
                       'day' : $scope.d,
                       'type' : 'get_restclosed' }),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).
    success (function(data, status, headers, config){
        if(data.success && !angular.isUndefined(data.data) ){
            $scope.closed = data.data;
        } else {
            $scope.closed = [];
        }
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        //$scope.messageFailure(data.message);
    });
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the most elegant way to resolve it is using the $q service of angular, this is a service to help you to run functions asynchronously.

```
$q.all([$http.get('http://...'), 
        $http.get('http://...'),
        $http.get('http://...')])
.then(function(values) {
        console.log(values[0].data); 
        console.log(values[1].data,
        console.log(values[2].data); 
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code and I think it will work as it is or with small modifications.

One more thing, according to angular docs, `success` has been deprecated and you should use standard `then` fuction.

```
$scope.getRestData = function () {
  var open;
    $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: "http://www.example.co.uk/php/x/open-get.php",
        data: $.param({ 'location' : $scope.l, 
                       'time' : $scope.t,
                       'day' : $scope.d,
                       'type' : 'get_restopen' }),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).
    then (function(data, status, headers, config){
        if(data.success && !angular.isUndefined(data.data) ){
            open = data.data;
        } else {
            open = [];
        }
      return $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: "http://www.ecample.co.uk/php/x/closed-get.php",
        data: $.param({ 'location' : $scope.l, 
                       'time' : $scope.t,
                       'day' : $scope.d,
                       'type' : 'get_restclosed' }),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
       });
    })
    .then(function(data, status, headers, config){
        if(data.success && !angular.isUndefined(data.data) ){
            $scope.closed = data.data;
        } else {
            $scope.closed = [];
        }
        $scope.open = open;
    })
};
```

function errorCallback (){

}

Comment: I'm not getting any data. Console error `$http(...).then(...).then(...).error is not a function`

Comment: Error gone but no data

Comment: debug your code and see what are you getting in first  `then` callback